# How do I format a double into a time with a print statement in Java?

Tags: java, integer, double, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a double into a time in Java.

Here is my current code:

```
int food_intake = 1000;
int calories_burned_per_hour = 173
double hours = food_intake / calories_burned_per_hour;
System.out.println("It will take you " + hours + " hours to burn that food off");
```

Here is the current output:

```
It will take you 5.78034682 hours to burn that food off
```

Here is the desired output:

```
It will take you 5 hours and 46 minutes to burn that food off
```

Any help is much appreciated - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculate the min part separately as below -

```
int food_intake = 1000;
int calories_burned_per_hour = 173;
double hours = food_intake / (calories_burned_per_hour * 1.0);

int hrPart = (int) hours;
int minPart = (int) ((hours - hrPart) * 60);

System.out.println("It will take you " + hrPart + " hours and " + minPart + " min to burn that food off");
```

Comment: if the answer works for you, feel free to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

## `Duration`

The [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline on the scale of hours, minutes, seconds, and nanos.

`Duration` works only with integer numbers, not fractional. So multiply your `double` to the granularity you desire: minutes, seconds, or nanos.

```java
double hours = 5.78034682d ;
double minutes = ( hours * 60d ) ; 
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( minutes ) ;

String output = d.toString() ;  // Standard ISO 8601 format. 
String h = d.toHoursPart() ;
String m = d.toMinutesPart() ;
```

Now ready to assemble your final string.